# select option by comparing ids

Tags: angular

in the role variable, I store the id of the role that the user has and I want to put selected the one that he has, for it I am comparing the id that is in ngFor, with the one that returns me the subscription

```
<div>
        <label for="role">Role:</label>
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
          <option *ngFor='let controlList of data' [value]="controlList.id" [selected]="controlList.id === 'role'">
            {{controlList.name}}
          </option>
        </select>
```

```
this.api.getRolByUser(userId)
      .subscribe( data => {
        this.role=data[0]['id'];
        console.log(data[0]['id']);
      });
```

Comment: Sorry, it isn't entirely clear what you are trying to achieve. Please rephrase your question and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: in that select, all the roles are listed, and I'm consulting which role the user has which I get from "getRolByUser" which returns me the id, which I want to put "selected" in the html @NicholasK

Comment: You should be able to get away with changing your `selectedOption` value to the ID returned in the role API. The select should update it's display accordingly if you have id's as your option values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `[(ngModel)]`, then just let that do the work for you instead of setting the `selected` attribute on the options.

This is the simplest implementation of a drop down I can think of.

html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" (ngModelChange)="onChange()">
  <option *ngFor="let item of data" [value]="item">
    {{item}}
  </option>
</select>
```

typescript

```
data = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
selectedOption: string;

ngOnInit() {
  this.selectedOption = 'b';
}

onChange() {
  console.log(this.selectedOption);
}
```

You are two-way binding the selected value to `selectedValue` by using `[(ngModel)]`. When the user selects a new value, `onChange` is called, and the `selectedValue` property has been updated.

You take care of getting your model correct, and let the select do the job of choose which option is selected.

So in your case, you should do the following in your typescript:

```
this.api.getRolByUser(userId).subscribe(data => {
  this.selectedOption = data[0]['id'];
});
```

And this in your HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
  <option *ngFor='let controlList of data' [value]="controlList.id">
    {{controlList.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zndty2

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in your selectedOption:

```
this.selectedOption = this.data.filter(item => item.id === this.role)[0];
```

check [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-form-select-elements-gcqx9m)

Comment: "this.selectedOption" does not receive the user's role, that variable I have to store to get the selected option when the user changes the option.

Comment: It's OK, but you need to fill it with the role you got from API in the first time: your default select option, If It's not so what do you want to do with [selected] ?

Comment: some way to make it like I am? [attr.selected]="controlList.id == role ? true : null"

Comment: They do the same It's following 2 way data binding by selected in your way the selectedOption will have selected value in the same time.

Comment: I'm trying to do as you say, but it's not working for me.